# how to assign an integer data type array values to a UITextField in iphone

Tags: objective-c

how to assign an integer data type array values to UITextField
because i have an integer array and i want to display its contents in the textfield

Comment: Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5959459/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
NSString *intergerString = [NSString StringWithFormat:@"%d",intergerValue];
txtField.text = intergerString;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 [*yourtextfieldname* setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",yourintegervalue]];
```