# how to assign an integer array to the UITextfield

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to assign an integer data type array values to a UITextField in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959459/how-to-assign-an-integer-data-type-array-values-to-a-uitextfield-in-iphone)

how to assign an integer data type array values to a UITextField in iphone
here is the code:

```
for(i=j;j>=0;j--) 
    {
        printf("%d",b[j]);
    }
    NSString *string =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", b];
    outputTextField.text = string;
```

but it does not works.

Comment: please dont ask the repeated questions here... if you have any doubt in my answer just ask here itself.....

Comment: Yeah that's very bad....

Comment: @Aravindhanarvi: If you know that a question is a duplicate, please flag it rather than answering.

Comment: @Inder Kumar Rathore: If you know that a question is a duplicate, please flag it rather than answering.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what are you trying to achieve, do you want whole array to be assigned to textfield or simply on element?

for a single element use

```
    NSString *string =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", b[elementNumber]];
    outputTextField.text = string;
```

if you are trying to assign whole array then use

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for(i=j;j>=0;j--) 
    {
        printf("%d",b[j]);
        [str appendFormat:@"%d",b[j]];
    }
    outputTextField.text = str;
    [str release];
```

Comment: i want to assign the whole array to the textfield

Comment: I have posted for both the cases... if you got your answer..just accept the answer and close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 NSMutablearray *array1;
    textfield.text=[array1 objectAtIndex:1];
```